# JSF error while passing method call in ui:param

Tags: jsf

I have the following code:

*some_file.xhtml* containing:

```
<ui:decorate template="template/a_template.xhtml">
    ...
    <ui:param name="doSmthg" value="#{aBean.someAction()}"/>
    ...
</ui:decorate>
```

And in the template file *a_template.xhtml*:

```
<p:commandLink id="anId" actionListener="#{doSmthg}" ...>
```

The issue here is that, aBean.someAction() is called normally but I've an error "`Identity 'doSmthg' was null and was unable to invoke`".

I don't have the error if I use directly `actionListener="#{aBean.someAction()}"` in the template though.

Does anyone have an idea ? Thx

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Passthe name of the method as parameter:

```
 <ui:param name="doSmthgName" value="someAction"/>
```

and use it:

```
<p:commandLink id="anId" actionListener="#{bean[doSmthgName]}" ...>
```